# What are the definitions of microstates and macrostates?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have been looking up definitions for [microstates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_%28statistical_mechanics%29) and macrostates of a thermodynamic-system.

I am looking for clear conditions for systems to be in the same macro- or microstate, but have had no luck in finding clear descriptions of them. What conditions do two systems need to satisfy for them to be considered in the same state, and what conditions for them to be in the same microstate? Do these conditions depend of the ensemble used or is this completely irrelevant?

Comment: They are in the same macrostate if they share the same values for the relevant set of macroscopic observables (which usually also imply that they share all macroscopic properties). They are in the same microsctate... well, if they share the same microscopic state.

Comment: Just read between the lines of Frank Lambert's [What is a microstate?](http://entropysite.oxy.edu/microstate/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **macrostate** is characterized by certain definite values of macroscopic variables (ones that you measure with tools of human scale; often called thermodynamic variables). For a simple hydrostatic system you might choose to have the whole system in the liquid state with temperature between $T$ and $T + \mathrm{d}T$ and pressure between $P$ and $P + \mathrm{d}P$.

A **microstate** is characterized by a particular volume in the systems phase space. For quantum systems this means a particular set of quantum numbers (in general very many quantum  numbers); for classical systems this is a volume from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x} + \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$ (where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector in the systems phases space and therefore will in general have very high dimensionality).

As a matter of course there are many microstates that correspond to each macrostate.

Comment: Is there one to one correspondence between the set of microstates and the macrostate? That is, can we have two different sets of microstates for the same macrostate?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others, a macrostate consists of macroscopic observables of a system. The system that I am referring to is normal quite large and may contain a huge number of microscopic constituents, whose exact states we don't really care about when talking about macrostates.

For microstates, then we have to specify the states for all of the constituents in the system, e.g. for a classical monatomic ideal gas, that would be the positions and momenta of all the gas molecules.

It's a bit tricky to put these concepts together with the **ensemble theory**, which consists of infinitely many copies of the system we are interested in.

1. For **microcanonical ensemble**, it's not that bad, since all the copies have exactly the same amount of energy, and all the other macroscopic observables are also the same. The only difference between these copies is that they may be in different possible micro states, because there are so many (microstates) and they are equally probable.
2. For **canonical ensemble**, it's slightly different. there can be energy exchange among the copies, even though the other macroscopic observables are the same. Therefore, in this case, for each copy of system the total energy will assume some value between 0 and $+\infty$ at any instant of time, and at this instant of time the system will be one of the many microstates corresponding to this particular value of total energy. However, if we now try to get out of the ensemble and focus on **the physical system**  instead of the copies, we then have to take the ensemble average of the all the copies in order to get the average energy, which will be the **macroscopically measured energy of the initial physical system**. In this case, the average energy actually comes with a standard deviation (fluctuation), which goes to 0 in the thermodynamic limit. In this case, it does not make physical sense to talk about the microstates corresponding to this average energy value, even though we can do so for each of the mental copies inside the ensemble.
3. for **grand canonical ensemble**, the situation is roughly the same with the canonical case. it's just that we have one more macroscopic variable (the number of particles) that can be varied among the copies of systems in the ensemble.